# Why are images imported as number?

Tags: react-native

```
import image from './image.png';
console.log(image) // returns some number
```

Why are images imported as numbers in React Native?

Comment: Images cannot be used so. Try this: `<Image source={require('./image.png')} style={{/*Your style*/}}/>`. That number, I guess, could be related to the hash code of the image.

Comment: `source={image}` does work though for some reason, just don't understand why. inline `require` gives a eslinter error

Comment: Ok, can you explain then what your error is, addsome context, logs, etc please? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: there is no error. the log is some number as i have indicated in the code. i'm just trying to understand the theory behind it (i.e. why it works differently from react.js)

Answer (score 0):

`require` image in React Native will be mapped as a number.

In `@types/react-native` React Native Typescript declaration, we can show like the following.

```
export type ImageSourcePropType = ImageURISource | ImageURISource[] | ImageRequireSource;
...
export type ImageRequireSource = number;
```

The `ImageRequireSource` is just an alias of `number` type and it can be a `ImageSourcePropType`.